# updating raster values based on polygon field in R terra

Tags: r, spatial, terra

I have a raster and vector with the same spatial extent. The raster has all values = 1.

What I want is to change the values in the raster based on which polygon they fall in.

```
library(terra)
## terra 1.7.19
f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
p <- vect(f)
p

r <- rast()
ext(r) <- ext(p)
r
values(r) <- 1

values(r)[p$NAME_1 == "Luxembourg",] <- 2
```

I was really hoping this code would make the areas called "Luxembourg" as value = 2, but instead it didn't, which means I clearly have the wrong idea.

Maybe someone else has a much better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data

```
library(terra)
p <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
r <- rast(p, res=0.01)
values(r) <- 1
```

A classical approach

```
lux <- p[p$NAME_1 == "Luxembourg",]
x <- rasterize(lux, r, 2, update=TRUE)
```

You could also do the last step with

```
r[lux] <- 3
```

So you were not far off. It works like this:

```
r[p[p$NAME_1 == "Luxembourg",]] <- 4
```

Comment: I found this answer very helpful. In my particular case I also need that the values to be updated are only those with one particular value. For this I created a new post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78219473/r-update-raster-values-which-fall-inside-a-polygon