# updating raster values with a vector or matrix of values based on polygon field in R terra

Tags: r, spatial, terra

Here I have a method to update selected parts of a raster with a new value (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76001114/updating-raster-values-based-on-polygon-field-in-r-terra/76001270#76001270)

```
library(terra)
p <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
r <- rast(p, res=0.01)
values(r) <- 1

lux <- p[p$NAME_1 == "Luxembourg",]
r[lux] <- 3
```

But now I would like to update the raster with a vector of values, rather than one value:

```
len <- nrow(r[lux]) 
r[lux] <- 1:len
# Error: [`[`] value is too long
```

I am not certain how to interpret the error, but I think it means I am passing the wrong data type to `r[lux]`. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of `lux` is four.

```
length(lux)
[1] 4
```

So you can replace the cell values with four new values.

```
r[lux] <- 11:14
```

I understand that you want to replace all cells covered by `lux` with a different number. That cannot be done with this type of replacement.

If your raster is not very large, you could achieve that with something like this

```
library(terra)
p <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
r <- rast(p, res=0.01)
values(r) <- 1
lux <- p[p$NAME_1 == "Luxembourg",]

x <- rasterize(lux, rast(r))
d <- as.data.frame(x, cells=TRUE)
x[d$cell] <- 1:nrow(d)

rr <- cover(x, r)
```

Or like this. The code looks very similar, but the result is different because the cells are here ordered by polygon.

```
e <- extract(r, lux, cell=TRUE, ID=FALSE)
x[e$cell] <- 1:nrow(e)
```