# R - update raster values which fall inside a polygon

Tags: r, gis, raster, terra

I'm working with environmental layers in R using terra. I want to modify the values of a raster that fall inside a polygon. I know the *classify* function that can update all the values of a raster, but I don't know how to apply this only to the area of the polygon. I also found [a nice and neat way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76001270/635245) to change all values inside a polygon, like this:

```
myraster[mypolygon] <- 7
```

but I just need to update one particular value, not all, for example, change all cells containg the value 21 for the value 7.

I unsuccessfully tried:

```
myraster[mypoligon][myraster[mypoligon] == 21] <- 7
```

getting the message:

> Error: [`[`] value is too long

As an alternative I'm thinking of getting the raster that intersects the polygon, then classify the values, and merge back this small raster with the original, but I wonder if a quicker process exists.

PS. I posted a reproducible example below as an answer.

Comment: Doesn't a temporary variable work? Something like `tmp <- myraster[mypolygon]; tmp[tmp == 21] <- 7; myraster[mypolygon] <- tmp`

Comment: @AllanCameron: Unfortunately not, this is also raising `Error: [`[`] value is too long`.

Comment: Thank you so much guys for the suggestion and for checking. I think I managed to solve it, I will post it as a reply.

Comment: When asking an R question, please always include a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example* (as is done in the answers, but you should have provided one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to get there using `cover`.

Example data

```
library(terra)
p <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))[3,]
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
```

Let's update the area of `r` that is covered by `p` to 400, but only if that area has values > 400.

```
x <- mask(r, p)
y <- clamp(x, -Inf, 400)
z <- cover(y, r)
```

If you wanted to change a particular value, let's say 482, to 1000 you could do

```
yy <- classify(x, cbind(482, 1000))
zz <- cover(yy, r)
```

And a range of values

```
yyy <- classify(x, cbind(480, 500, 1000))
zzz <- cover(yyy, r)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Robert Hijmans. This approach is neat! To make it clear, I guess we need to replace the 'clamp' line with the classification function, in case one is only interested in changing one value, for example the values 300 for 500 or as in the example by  @dimfalk 350 ==> 1000.

Comment: It would be great if you could edit the 'clamp' line so that if changes just one value. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a one-liner, and probably there are more elgant approaches, but this gets the job done (basically chaining terra's mask, classify and merge):

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.71

# sample data
r <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package = "terra") |> terra::rast()
v <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package = "terra") |> terra::vect()

# subset raster
mask <- v[12, ]
r_sub <- terra::mask(r, mask, touches = FALSE)

# reclassify, here: 350 -> 1000
m <- c(350, 350, 1000) |> matrix(ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

r_rcl <- terra::classify(r_sub, rcl = m, include.lowest = TRUE)

# merge again, pay attention to the order of the arguments 
r2 <- terra::merge(r_rcl, r)
r2
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 90, 95, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
#> extent      : 5.741667, 6.533333, 49.44167, 50.19167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#> source(s)   : memory
#> varname     : elev 
#> name        : elevation 
#> min value   :       141 
#> max value   :      1000

terra::plot(r2)
terra::plot(mask, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-25 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**Edit:** Oh, should have read your complete question. Just noticed I proposed exactly the alternative approach you described :(

Comment: Thank you so much @dimfalk. This  was the above mentioned alternative but I didn't remember how to implement the code, and   you ilustrated it with a beautiful example :)  thanks!!

Comment: Just changed `crop()` to `mask(..., touches = FALSE)` since I realized that we would include pixel values outside the polygon, but inside its bbox otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself a possible solution following the idea posted here: [updating raster values with a vector or matrix of values based on polygon field in R terra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76010155/updating-raster-values-with-a-vector-or-matrix-of-values-based-on-polygon-field).

The thing is accessing the values directly, eg.:

```
myraster[cells_id] <- 7
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.7.55

# sample data
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package = "terra"))
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package = "terra"))[6,]
plot(r)
polys(v)

# Get a raster with the shape of the polygon and the same resolution of r
raster_polygon <- rasterize(v, r)

# Get the cell ids and values
cells_id <- as.data.frame(raster_polygon, cells = TRUE)
cells_id <- cells_id$cell
cell_values <- r[cells_id]

# Change the values keeping then in a vector
cell_values[cell_values == 300] <- 500

# Assign those values to the raster
r[cells_id] <- cell_values

plot(r)
polys(v)
```

Here are the maps, before and after the value update (notice the green dots):

[image: Original raster]

[image: updated raster]